# SQL JOIN average value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I need some help for optimization of my query

I have two tables

**Table 1** - `users_location`; **Table 2** - `users_rating`

```
+-------+---------+      +-------+--------+
|user   | location|      | user  | rating | 
+-------+---------+      +-------+--------+
| user1 |   AA    |      | user1 |   1    |
| user2 |   BB    |      | user1 |   3    |
| user3 |   CC    |      | user1 |   4    |
| user4 |   AA    |      | user2 |   3    |
| user5 |   BB    |      | user4 |   2    |
| user6 |   CC    |      | user4 |   4    |
```

I need select users and their average rating by  location(AA for example).
Now my query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_loaction AS TABLE1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  
        user, 
        AVG(rating) 
    FROM users_rating group by user
) AS TABLE2 
ON  TABLE1.user = TABLE2.user
WHERE TABLE1.location = AA
```

I think SQL will calculate average rating by all users and then join only that i need, this is not optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `mysql` you can try this:

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM users_rating AS ur WHERE ur.user = ul.user ) AS rating
FROM users_location AS ul
WHERE ul.location = 'AA';
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0bd4/1).

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c34c8d/1

```
SELECT t.*, AVG(t2.rating) 
FROM users_location t
LEFT JOIN  users_rating t2
ON  t.user = t2.user 
WHERE t.location = 'AA'
GROUP BY t.Location;

SELECT t.*, AVG(t2.rating) 
FROM users_location t
LEFT JOIN  users_rating t2
ON  t.user = t2.user 
WHERE t.location = 'AA'
GROUP BY t.user;

SELECT t.*, AVG(t2.rating) 
FROM users_location t
LEFT JOIN  users_rating t2
ON  t.user = t2.user 
WHERE t.location = 'AA'
GROUP BY t.Location, t.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback from Rick, below are answers for both MySQL and SQL Server:

**MySQL**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e9be8/1

```
SELECT l.user, AVG(r.rating) FROM users_location l
    LEFT JOIN users_rating r ON l.user = r.user
    WHERE l.location = 'AA'
    GROUP BY l.user
```

**SQL Server**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/379e6/1

```
SELECT l.[user], AVG(r.rating) FROM users_location l
    LEFT JOIN users_rating r ON l.[user] = r.[user]
    WHERE l.location = 'AA'
    GROUP BY l.[user]
```

Comment: No [] brackets in MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames, thanks for the info. By the tags, I'm not sure if the OP is looking for an answer that works on both MySQL and SQL Server, or either one or the other. I just edited my answer to specify that my answer is for SQL Server.

Comment: How to accomplish this when there are a lot of other columns and I don't want to have to group by all of them?